# event id 4663 not shown over network

Tags: events, networking

I have a map on computer A shared and enabeled for auditing.
indeed when I trow a file in this map I notice the event 4663 id..

However when I do this from another Pc to the same shared map nothing shows up in the event viewer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a little old but posting anyway.
I had the same issue and solved it by enabling additional Policy 'File Share' to 'Success'. You should get Event Id 4663 as desired after this is applied to File Server.

**Set this to [Success]:** Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Advanced Audit Policy Configuration\Audit Policies\Object Access: File Share